# JSTL and refactor renaming under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl

I would like to use JSTL (yes, not JSF) inside our Java EE project. We use a POJO in the request attributes, and we would print their content using c:out.

If I rename a getter inside the POJO, `c:out` does not get updated (using Eclipse).

I would have expected it to be renamed during the refactoring. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, `eclipse` will not refactor method names in `JSP` files

Second, You don't need to call the getter in `JSTL`, Just access the field directly, like this:

```
 <c:out value="${employee.firstName}"/>
```

Third, just make sure that your getter **name** in the form of

```
 public String getFirstName(){
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Eclipse does refactor method names in JSPs (or maybe that's a JBoss Tools I use). You're right about not using getters, I don't, but I'm afraid that renaming the method won't update the field.